# Sending post variables to a framed page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a framed page that I am using as an editor. The left side has different pages for editing pages on the sever. On the right side it opens the page so that you can see what  the result looks like. I have been using frames as I can change the page on the left or right and not worry about losing what I have typed in on the other side.

Now I am wondering about add in a feature where I can create a link that will open this framed page, and post data to one of the .php frames

The post to the frame would be like this.

```
www.mysite.com/left.php?editfile=Ranch.xml&type=panoeditlist
```

Calling that does not work as it will just give me that single page and not open the frame with the second side.

It seems like there should be a way of doing something like

```
www.mysite.com/frameholder.html Send to leftframe ?editfile=Ranch.xml&type=panoeditlist
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass  your parameters to `frameholder.html`. In JavaScript code for that page you need to extract those parameters using `location.search` property. Then you need to set SRC of your left frame by combining URL of your PHP page with these extracted parameters.